oracle throws exception with message "Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value"
I have code that call Oracle funqtion:
public Map<String, Object> canRefuse(int val) {
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withSchemaName("custom")
            .withCatalogName("pkg")
            .withFunctionName("foo");

    SqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("val", val);

    return simpleJdbcCall.execute(parameterSource);
}

but It throws exception:
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{? = call custom.pkg.foo(?)}] ...
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value ORA-06512: at "custom.pkg", line 1207 ORA-06512: at line 1

I could not find any way to overcome this problem

This error indicates a bug in the PL/SQL function you are calling. In languages such as C# or Java, a non-void method must always return a value, and it's a compilation error if the compiler can find some way to get to the end of the method without hitting a return statement. The Oracle PL/SQL compiler does not make this check. What is happening is that the end of the function has been reached without the function returning anything. If you could edit your question to include the definition of this function, we could potentially tell you why this is happening.

I agree with what Luke said, provide us with function definition, probably that function under given parameters is never reaching return clause (i hope your function has a return clause). Inspect your conditinal logics, if else statements if your return depends on them.  Also look at exception block, check if how errors are handled and returned.

ORA-06512

unfortunately I am restricted to see function definition. I can see only its name and parameters. :(
